# How does Partitioning By a Substring in T-SQL Work?

Tags: sql, t-sql, concatenation, partitioning, for-xml-path

I found the perfect example while browsing through sites of what I'm looking for. In this code example, all country names that appear in long formatted rows are concatenated together into one result, with a comma and space between each country.

```
Select CountryName from Application.Countries; 
 
Select SUBSTRING( 
( 
     SELECT ',' + CountryName AS 'data()'
         FROM Application.Countries FOR XML PATH('') 
), 2 , 9999) As Countries
```

Source: https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/concatenate-multiple-rows-into-single-string

My question is: how can you partition these results with a second column that would read as "Continent" in such a way that each country would appear within its respective continent? The theoretical "OVER (PARTITION BY Continent)" in this example would not work without an aggregate function before it. Perhaps there is a better way to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a continents table to look at the countries and match them to the corresponding continent? Is the continent saved on your Application.Countries table?

Comment: Continent, in this example, would be another column on the Application.Countries table, alongside all the rows of countries.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? If relatively modern (> 2016) you should prefer `STRING_AGG`, the tool *designed* for string aggregation over the FOR XML PATH hack.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever but George's solution worked. I have SSMS 2017, but STRING_AGG was giving me an error when I tried it yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a continents table (you seem not to have one, so derive one with `distinct`), and then use the same code in a `cross apply` using the `where` as a "join" condition:

```
select *
from
(
    select distinct continent from Application.Countries
) t1
cross apply
(
    Select SUBSTRING( 
    ( 
        SELECT ',' + CountryName AS 'data()'
        FROM Application.Countries as c FOR XML PATH('') 
        where c.continent=t1.continent
    ), 2 , 9999) As Countries
) t2
```

Note that it is more usual, and arguably has more finesse, to use `stuff(x,1,1,'')`instead of `substring(x,2,9999)` to remove the first comma.